# Django dynamic filterset

Tags: python, django, multiple-inheritance, metaclass, django-filter

So I want to create a [django filters.FilterSet](https://django-filter.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ref/filters.html) from [django-filter module](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-filter), but I want to dynamically add its attributes. For example, if I wanted to add `SubName` dynamically:

```
class UsersInfoFilter(filters.FilterSet):
    Name=NumberFilter(lookup_type='gte')
    def __new__(self):
        self.SubName=NumberFilter(lookup_type='gte')
        self.Meta.fields.append('SubName')
    class Meta:
        model = UsersInfo
        fields = ['UserID', 'LanguageID', 'Name']
```

The problem is that FilterSet is a metaclass that immediately runs once the class has been figured out, so there is nowhere before that point that items can be dynamically added.

I've tried putting a function in as a parameter around filters.FilterSet `class UsersInfo(AddObjects(filters.FilterSet))` which returns exactly what is passes, but I cannot reference `UsersInfoFilter` at that point since it still isn't finished being created.

I also tried making `UsersInfoFilter` its own base class, and then creating a `class RealUsersInfoFilter(UsersInfoFilter, filters.FilterSet)` as my actual filter, but then FilterSet just throws warnings about missing attributes named as fields.

There doesn't seem to be any kind of constructor function for classes in python. I'm assuming I have to do some kind of magic with metaclasses, but I've tried every combination I can think of and am at wits end.

Comment: You should add the `django-filter` tag to maximize the chances of getting an answer.

Comment: Did you ever find an answer for this? I'm stuck on something similar.

Comment: Unfortunately, a solution was never forthcoming.

Comment: Take a look at this which helps applying filters on queryset based on url params https://github.com/manjitkumar/drf-url-filters

Answer (score 0):

You can't change `Meta` subclass from the `__init__` method... there are 2 options to approach your issue...

First one - define "wide" filter on all of the model fields:

```
class UsersInfoFilter(filters.FilterSet):
    class Meta:
        model = UsersInfo
```

It will create default filters for all your model fields.

Second, define dynamic fields:

```
class UsersInfoFilter(filters.FilterSet):
    name = NumberFilter(lookup_type='gte')

    def __init__(self):
        super(UsersInfoFilter, self).__init__()

        base_filters['subname'] = NumberFilter(name='subname', lookup_type='gte')

    class Meta:
        model = UsersInfo
        fields = ['user_id', 'language_id', 'name']
```

(I do not know if this is something you really want - because despite "dynamic" adding field - it should be declared as static - there are no logic here)

p.s.
why CamelCase on properties and fields? use proper pep-8.

Answer (score 0):

To dynamically choose the fields in the FilterSet, I suggest to create a FilterSet factory like this:

```
def filterset_factory(model, fields):

    meta = type(str('Meta'), (object,), {'model': model, 'fields': fields})

    filterset = type(str('%sFilterSet' % model._meta.object_name),
                 (FilterSet,), {'Meta': meta})

    return filterset
```

And then use it like:

```
DynamicFilterClass = filterset_factory(model=MyModel, fields=[...])
dynamic_filter = DynamicFilterClass(request.GET, queryset=instances)
```